# Sharepoint Pragma Header

Tags: html

someone know what is this Header and if i really need it?

```
Pragma: SharePointAjaxDelta=|SITES|SC1|0A18C942-C443-4D91-954B-E6A2BF6B6061:|SITES|SC1|_CATALOGS|MASTERPAGE|TT.MASTER:1.15.0.0.0.15.0.4763.1000.2.FALSE.:en-US:en-US:RW
```

Thanks

Comment: where did you find this and what version of sharepoint.